# How to find Numbers before closing node Element in XML

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-2.0

I try to find string before closing element e.g. (`277, 288`) then replace `$1` return s/b `277`. `(&lt;)` not support my regex
**Input XML**

```
<root>
<p>Magno v College Network, Inc. (2016) 1 CA5th 277, 288</p>
<p>Magno v College Network, Inc. (5, 2017) 1 CA5th 15, 288 SA</p>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '([0-9]+),\s[0-9]+(&lt;)', '$1')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**Expected output**

```
 <root>
   <p>Magno v College Network, Inc. (2016) 1 CA5th 277</p>
   <p>Magno v College Network, Inc. (5, 2017) 1 CA5th 15, 288 SA</p>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of numbers, only positive integers without any leading `+` or `-` symbol? Anyway, if you match with regular expressions, then the metacharacter `$` indicates a match on the end of the string perhaps using it in your expression, as in `'([0-9]+),\s[0-9]+$'`, suffices.

Comment: Martin Sir Thanks for the Help!